# How to run APB Infinite on Linux?

Tags: windows, raspberry-pi, wine, games

I want to use Raspberry Pi to run the [APB Infinite Neverwinter bot](http://www.ownedcore.com/forums/mmo/neverwinter/neverwinter-bots-programs/440080-apb-infinite.html).
I cannot make in work using Wine even on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I did not download and look into those `.rar` files, but presumably they contain windows *binaries*.

On the off chance that they contain *portable* source code, you may be able to compile whatever it is on the pi.  If not, you are out of luck, plain and simple; there are [some comments here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=41444) about the availability of windows on the pi, but to make a long story short: *do not waste your time thinking about it.*  There is no version of MS Windows for ARMv6, and running an x86 emulator on the pi will be totally ridiculous.  For example, there's [stuff like this](http://store.raspberrypi.com/projects/rpix86) for running old DOS games, giving you a whopping 20Mhz 80486...

You could look into getting an [official (free) windows image](http://www.computersnyou.com/1480/2013/02/microsoft-officially-offering-ready-made-virtualbox-and-vmware-images-for-internet-explorer-testing/) for virtualbox and running it under linux -- but not on the pi.  It just does not have the power no matter how you slice it (also, virtualbox will not run on ARM at all, I believe).

Comment: And isn't there wine for Pi? Could someone try to run the app under wine? Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this in Wine on Fedora 19 and it bombs out.

```
$ cd 0.4.5/ && ls -l
total 2028
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml  167936 Nov  6 22:19 APBInfinite.exe
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml    4096 Nov  6 22:43 Errors
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml 1754624 Jul 29  2013 Geckofx-Core.dll
-rw-rw-r--. 1 saml saml  128512 Jul 29  2013 Geckofx-Winforms.dll
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml    4096 Nov  6 22:42 Professions
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml    4096 Nov  6 22:43 Routes
drwxrwxr-x. 2 saml saml    4096 Nov  6 22:44 Settings
drwxrwxr-x. 4 saml saml    4096 Nov  6 22:43 xulrunner
```

There is no source distributed with this software so you're only recourse is going to be running it inside of Wine, or natively on Windows.

```
$ wine APBInfinite.exe
```

err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"C:\windows\mono\mono-2.0\bin\libmono-2.0-x86.dll") not found
err:mscoree:load_mono Could not load Mono into this process

Seems to want Mono. Do you have that application installed into Wine. That would seem to be the tripping point. It would seem, at least according to the Wine Wiki, that you can install Mono.

- http://wiki.winehq.org/Mono

Comment: Installed mono, got "The entry point method could not be loaded
"

Comment: @user61143 - You installed mono within Wine?

Comment: Yup. see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/116748/61143

Comment: @user61143 - no that is using mono on Linux. You need to install it into Wine. `$ Wine mono-install..` first. Then run your APB.

Comment: In wine I get he exact same output.

Comment: @user61143 - did you follow ALL the directions on this page? http://wiki.winehq.org/Mono.

Comment: Which ones do you mean?

Comment: @user61143 - Everything at the top.

Comment: Wine 1.5.6 will install Wine Mono automatically as needed. It will search for the MSI in the following locations:[..] ?

Comment: @user61143 - if that's true then I don't think you're going to get much further then I did. I have a very new version of wine: `$ wine --version
wine-1.7.8`.