# How to fix library problem with mono on Debian?

Tags: mono, .net

I installed mono and when trying to run an app:

```
a@debianVM:~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT$ mono ./APBInfinite.exe 
Mono: gc took 12 usecs
(sip)
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: Searching for 'XReparentWindow'.
Mono: Probing 'XReparentWindow'.
Mono: Found as 'XReparentWindow'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: Searching for 'XRaiseWindow'.
Mono: Probing 'XRaiseWindow'.
Mono: Found as 'XRaiseWindow'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: Searching for 'XConfigureWindow'.
Mono: Probing 'XConfigureWindow'.
Mono: Found as 'XConfigureWindow'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: Searching for 'XLowerWindow'.
Mono: Probing 'XLowerWindow'.
Mono: Found as 'XLowerWindow'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'user32'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libuser32.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libuser32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'user32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'user32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libuser32.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libuser32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libMonoSupportW.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libMonoSupportW.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libMonoSupportW.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libMonoSupportW.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libMonoSupportW.so'.
Mono: Searching for 'GetFocus'.
Mono: Probing 'GetFocus'.
Mono: Probing 'GetFocus'.
Mono: Probing 'GetFocusA'.
Mono: Probing 'GetFocusA'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'user32'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libuser32.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libuser32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'user32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'user32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libuser32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libuser32.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libuser32.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libuser32'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libuser32: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libMonoSupportW.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libMonoSupportW.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libMonoSupportW.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libMonoSupportW.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libMonoSupportW.so'.
Mono: Searching for 'IsChild'.
Mono: Probing 'IsChild'.
Mono: Probing 'IsChild'.
Mono: Probing 'IsChildA'.
Mono: Probing 'IsChildA'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: '__Internal'.
Mono: Searching for 'SetDllDirectory'.
Mono: Probing 'SetDllDirectoryW'.
Mono: Probing 'SetDllDirectoryW'.
Mono: Probing 'SetDllDirectory'.
Mono: Probing 'SetDllDirectory'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'xul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport unable to load library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'xul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport unable to load library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'xul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport unable to load library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'xul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport unable to load library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'xul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport unable to load library 'libxul: cannot open shared object fSystem.DllNotFoundException: xul
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gecko.Xpcom:NS_InitXPCOM2 (Gecko.nsIServiceManager&,object,Gecko.nsIDirectoryServiceProvider)
  at Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize (System.String binDirectory) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser.OnHandleCreated (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gecko.GeckoWebBrowser.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlWindowTarget.OnMessage (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc (System.Windows.Forms.Message& m) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WndProc (IntPtr hWnd, Msg msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
ile: No such file or directory'.
Mono: Assembly Ref addref Geckofx-Core[0x8b1a098] -> System[0x8ab8628]: 9
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'xul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'xul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/home/a/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BOT/libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libxul.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library: 'libxul.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading: 'libxul'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport unable to load library 'libxul: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: gc took 1115 usecs
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libgdiplus.so.0'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libgdiplus.so.0'.
Mono: Searching for 'GdipDeleteFontFamily'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipDeleteFontFamily'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipDeleteFontFamily'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libgdiplus.so.0'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0.so'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/libgdiplus.so.0.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading location: 'libgdiplus.so.0'.
Mono: Searching for 'GdipDeleteFont'.
Mono: Probing 'GdipDeleteFont'.
Mono: Found as 'GdipDeleteFont'.
Mono: DllImport attempting to load: 'libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6'.
Mono: DllImport error loading library '/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory'.
Mono: DllImport loading library: '/usr/lib/monSystem.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Gecko.GeckoPreferences ---> System.DllNotFoundException: xul
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gecko.Xpcom:NS_InitXPCOM2 (Gecko.nsIServiceManager&,object,Gecko.nsIDirectoryServiceProvider)
  at Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize (System.String binDirectory) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gecko.Xpcom.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gecko.GeckoPreferences..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at APBInfinite.BrowserWindow.Form1_Load (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoadInternal (System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

[Full logs](http://pastebin.com/ACwuy34i)

Any solutions?

Comment: Why do you expect this to work in mono without wine?

Comment: That's why: http://askubuntu.com/a/122628

Comment: What is the output of `MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug mono ./APBInfinite.exe`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ACwuy34i

Comment: There is some confusion around this Q and the related one: http://askubuntu.com/a/122628. Ultimately the OP is trying to get APB (other Q) to work in Wine. But APB needs Mono. The Mono that is needed, needs to be INSTALLED INTO Wine, not use the native version of Mono that is available on Linux! So one would have to do something like `$ wine run-mono-installer`.

Comment: As I stated in the other Q, the details on this page from the Wine Wiki will have to be followed exactly if you have any hope of getting Mono to run correctly within the Wine env. http://wiki.winehq.org/Mono